# How to make an exe file out of Python Scrapy script?

Tags: python, exe, scrapy

I have a Scrapy script, and it's working fine. To distribute it to my friends, I need it to be executable because they don't know much about Scrapy. Would someone tell me how to turn a Scrapy script into an exe file?

Is py2exe applicable in this regard?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, use py2exe

Ask questions about any specific problems you have.

Comment: Did you succeed in doing this? I will give it a try, but would be interested in any points I may need to pay attention too.

Comment: @SamS, I've not done it with scrapy, but most of the time py2exe just works. And if it doesn't work, you don't know until you try. So try!

Comment: Hehe thanks for info, never did py2exe yet and I have a feeling that scrapy may have some issues, but won't know until I try. I saw somebody on Google who tried it and did not succeed, but that may be his problem ;)