# Make an exe of a scrapy spider

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I have this scrapy spider that i want to convert to exe file. Tried py2exe and pyinstaller but no luck. Any suggestions on how to make it a single executable file. The start urls also needs to be changed, so that should also be condsidered.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re

import scrapy
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


class YuSpider(CrawlSpider):
    custom_settings = {
        'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS': 1
    }
    name = 'yu'
    allowed_domains = ['farfeshplus.com',
                       'wintv.live']

    start_urls = ['https://www.farfeshplus.com/Video.asp?ZoneID=1517']

    # uncomment __init__ function if u want to use from command line and comment out start urls

    # def __init__(self, name=None, **kwargs):
    #     if 'start_urls' in kwargs:
    #         self.start_urls = kwargs.pop('start_urls').split(',')
    #     super(YuSpider, self).__init__(name, **kwargs)

    rules = (
        Rule(LinkExtractor(restrict_css='td td td tr:nth-child(3) a'), callback='parse_item', follow=True),

    )

    def parse_item(self, response):
        for url in response.xpath('//html'):
            response.meta['NAME'] = url.xpath('//h1/div/text()').extract()

            frames = url.xpath('//iframe[@width="750"]/@src').extract_first()

            yield scrapy.Request(url=frames, callback=self.parse_frame, meta=response.meta)

    def parse_frame(self, response):
        name = response.meta['NAME']
        URL = response.xpath('//body/script').extract_first()
        try:
            mp4 = re.compile(r"(?<=mp4:\s\[\')(.*)\'\]")
            link = mp4.findall(URL)[0]
        except IndexError:
            mp4 = re.compile(r"(?<=hls:\s')(.*)'")
            link = mp4.findall(URL)[0]

        yield {
            'NAME': name,
            'Link': link,
        }
```

Comment: What kind error have you when use pyinstaller ?.....I use ConfigParser for pass all parameter from a file .ini to file python....may you can use that ..

Comment: it gives no error but the exe doesnt run properly.... it just opens cmd  and closes insatntly...can't even see whats going on

Comment: ok , but if you try first open cmd and later run the exe? ....like this C:\Users> myexec.exe

Comment: File "websc\spiders\yu.py", line 4, in <module>
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'D:\\fivsec\\websc\\websc\\spiders\\dist\\yu\\scrapy\\VERSION'
 Failed to execute script yu

Comment: this is error when ran through cmd

Comment: wait , but are you try run the file .py ....

Comment: nope i tried to run exe

Comment: check this example  https://datatofish.com/executable-pyinstaller/

Comment: did the same no luck

Comment: Possible duplicate of [python scrapy conversion to exe file using pyinstaller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50493828/python-scrapy-conversion-to-exe-file-using-pyinstaller)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to make an exe file out of Python Scrapy script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8114839/how-to-make-an-exe-file-out-of-python-scrapy-script)